# html on mobile: fit width both in firefox and chrome app

Tags: html, mobile

In my head, I declare

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes", target-densitydpi="device-dpi" />
```

When opening my page with the Chrome application for Android, the page is nicely fitted in the width. But when opening it with the Firefox app, it is slightly zoomed in and the page looks ugly, because it is cutted. Is there anything missing?

Comment: May not be the problem of this header. Any other codes that can show us?

Comment: Are you resetting default browser css?

Comment: How can I reset the default browser css? just overwrite it?